# running my Asp.net MVC project on godaddy host has Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have developed an asp.net MVC project . I created a folder named `firstone` and drag all the project files to that folder. it works fine right now . I am not sure if the godaddy them selves made any changes to it or not but it works fine in (www.forexample.com/firstone)...

but it seems the host does not accept any other MVC project. I archived and download everything from that project which have been working fine  and uploaded again in another new folder named nextone by URL (www.forexample.com/nextone) but amazingly it has Error. how is it possible that a project works fine in a folder and exactly same one does not work in another new folder in same host.

here is my webconfig

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
    <section name="ML_VoiceRecorderFree1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
     </sectionGroup>
     </configSections>


 <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>



 <system.web>
 <trust level="Full"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

  <staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge ="8.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />

  </staticContent>

  </system.webServer>
 <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="--------"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="--------"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="--------"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="------"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="--------"/>
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Will Go to IIS Management and you will create one Folder with Name (nextone) and tick **Set Application Root** and **Anonymous Access** with 
you need to create same Folder name in IIS Management

Comment: oh thank you very very much 100...000 times. it solved